# Find $ \ z \ $ if $ \ z \ \cdot \ (2cis60) \ = \ 4$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find $ \ z \ $ if  $ \ z \ \cdot \ (2cis60) \ = \ 4$, where $ \ z \ = \ r \ cis(\theta) \ $

I am taking year 12 specialist math and came across this question. I was wondering if my method is correct.

$$z \ = \ r \ cis(\theta) \ \cdot \ 2cis60 \ = \ 4 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ cis(\theta+60) \ = \ 2 $$

Then I expanded this into: $ \ r \ \cos(\theta+60) \ + \ i \ r \ \sin(\ \theta+60) \ = \ 2$
I then equated the imaginary component of the equation to 0 and found $ \ \theta \ $ and thus r. This gave me 2cis120. Is this answer and the method correct?

Comment: Isn't $ \ 2 \ = \ 2 \ cis \ 0 \ $ ?  Inserting your result into the original equation gives a product of $ \ -2 \ $ .  (I also edited your title, since the right-hand side didn't agree with that of the equation in the body of the post.)

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax.  If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Don't forget to equate the _real_ parts as well.

Answer (score 0):

We would have:

$$z=\frac2{cis(60)}$$

Use $\frac1{cis(x)}=cis(-x)$

$$z=2cis(-60)=2(\cos(-60)+i\sin(-60))$$

$$z=2(\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2)$$

$$z=1-i\sqrt{3}$$